# How do I control the origin to my scale?

Tags: modeling, scale

I was following a tutorial to creating an anvil and had a question in mind. When creating this Anvil, I came to a step where I had to create the tip of the anvil- keep in mind that I made the point too long. 
Without thinking too much, I committed to the length and I created 5 edge loops that were evenly distributed along the length.

I guess you can see my problem now. Having committed to a longer length of the point, I now had to make the length shorter while keeping the edge loop evenly separated and intact to the body of the anvil.

Being a Photoshop user, I thought "oh no problem I can just scale it", but when I scaled it, I realized that I'm limited to scaling in the center of my selection- it was not from the side I needed to scale it from. 
I will attach images to best explain what I have, versus what I was thinking of.

I do know that I can just backtrack or be more careful next time, but if there is a tool for something like this, I believe it would be very useful in the future!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use 3D cursor as pivot point :).

1. Select the edge loop and put 3D cursor there. *Mesh > Snap > Cursor To selected.*
2. Set Pivot point to *3D Cursor*.
3. Use Scale tool gizmo to scale only on X axis.

[image]